# Overload inherited methods in an Rcpp class

Tags: c++, rcpp

I have two classes `A`, the parent and `B`, the child.
`B` overloads a method from `A`. The problem is that the method `getval` is not overloaded when exposing class `B` in an RCPP module, despite explicitly exposing it again a second time with a pointer to `B::getval`.

Is it due to a bug in Rcpp, a limitation or something I just don't know yet?

```cpp
class A
{
public:
    A(int val) : val(val) {}

        int getval()
        {
                Rcout << "I am A" << endl;
                return val;
        }

private:
    int val;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
        using A::A;

        int getval()
        {
                Rcout << "I am B" << endl;
                return A::getval();
        }
};

RCPP_MODULE(rg)
{
    using namespace Rcpp;

    class_<A>("A")
        .constructor<int>()
        .method("getval", &A::getval);

    class_<B>("B")
        .derives<A>("A")
        .constructor<int>()
        .method("getval", &B::getval);
}
```

Comment: I think we describe this in the `Rcpp Modules` vignette. There are some limitations because we provide access to a more limited C language API from C++ not all bells and whistles can be had.

Comment: Thanks @DirkEddelbuettel, page 6 of the `Rcpp Modules` [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf) brought me the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I use my basic example above (in the question) in a simple C++ program as follows:

```cpp
int main()                                                                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                                                            
    A a(42);                                                                                                                                                                                  
    B b(43);                                                                                                                                                                                  
                                                                                                                                                                                      
    cout << a.getval() << endl;                                                                                                              
    cout << b.getval() << endl;                                                                                            
}
```

the correct method will be used. However, with `Rcpp`, the parent class `A` must declare the method `getval` as `virtual`:

```cpp
virtual int getval()
```

In fact, it's good to declare the same method in `B` as `virtual` too. In `R`, it will finally work as expected:

```R
a <- A$new(42)
b <- B$new(43)
```

Then:

```R
a$getval()
I am A
[1] 42

b$getval()
I am B
I am A
[1] 43
```

Note that the message `I am A` under `I am B` is expected because in my example I do an explicit call the `A::getval`.

Comment: Nice and clean demo!