# Rcpp modules: can't access fields/methods from a superclass

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a class A that inherits from another class B, and I want to expose class A using Rcpp. I can access any items that are part of A, but I'm having problems accessing fields/methods that are defined in B.

Here's some simple code:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass(int const& n, double const& x)
        : n(n), x(x)
    {}

    int func1(int m) const
    {
        return m * n;
    }

protected:
    int n;
    double x;
};

class RTestClass : public TestClass
{
public:
    RTestClass(int const& in_n, double const& in_x)
        : TestClass(in_n, in_x)
    {}
};

RCPP_MODULE(RTestClassModule)
{
    class_<RTestClass>("RTestClass")
    .constructor<int, double>()
    .method("func1", &TestClass::func1, "func1");
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get a crap-ton* of compiler errors which appear to be template-related. The same thing happens if I change `&TestClass::func1` to `&RTestClass::func1`.

I can create a wrapper function in `RTestClass` that calls `TestClass::func1` and use that in the module. It's clumsy though, and the sort of boilerplate wrapping that I was hoping Rcpp would do automatically.

Is there a problem with how I'm using modules?

This is with R 4.1.1 on Windows 10 and Rcpp 1.0.7.

<sup>* technical term</sup>

Comment: Does [this very recent question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70029743/overload-inherited-methods-in-an-rcpp-class) help you?

Comment: Hi @DirkEddelbuettel, no, that doesn't work. One difference is that I don't have a `func1` in the child class, but regardless, adding `virtual` doesn't change things.

Comment: Well "the sort of boilerplate wrapping that I was hoping Rcpp would do automatically" we do a lot things in the package but _magic_ is not one of them.  There are some constraints to what we can do _due to the C interface R offers_ and I believe the Rcpp Modules documentation states that multiple inheritance is not available.  You still get your money back though :)   Kidding aside, Modules is good for simple things, quickly.  Complex interfaces remain more work than simple ones.

Comment: That's fair enough, but this isn't multiple inheritance though, just simple inheritance

Comment: I haven't had time to study your post in detail but maybe you "just" have to list the methods you want access in the `RCPP_MODULE()` section?

Comment: `class_<TestClass>("TestClass") .constructor<int, double>() .method("func1", &TestClass::func1);   class_<RTestClass>("RTestClass") .constructor<int, double>() .derives<TestClass>("TestClass") ;` -- is this the kind of verbosity that you are hoping to avoid?